# Retrieving Video and Background image from database using cideigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

How do I obtain an image and use it as a background from my database and I obtain a video and display it on my site. I am using codeigntier.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @cosmoonot I have linked my site to my database as I can already retreive other stuff. For a background I USED THIS "<body background="<?php foreach($BACLGROUND as $bg) { echo "<div>".$bg['bgImage']."</div>";}?>">"  and in attempt to recive a video I used this; "<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="<?php foreach($VIDEO as $v)  {echo .$v['VIDEOO'].;}?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the image path in any db field.

- Store the image or video url in database table. `Ex. tbl_settings`
- Query the database and get the image or video URL.
- Use the image or video url in css background property.

Ex:

```
$this->db->select('settings_value')->from('tbl_settings');
$this->db->where(array('settings_key'=>'home_bg'));
$res=$this->db->get();
$home_bg='no-img.jpg';
if($res)
{
   $home_bg=$res->row();
}
```

Write the following CSS code in your view file.

```
<style>
#home_bg_style{
   background-image: url("<?php echo $home_bg;?>");
   height:100px;
}
</style>
```

In View file HTML

```
<div id="home_bg_style">

</div>
```

Similarly, you can implement for Video.